# Micronaut HTTP Client Fails to Bind Response that is Missing Content-Type Header

Tags: rest, grails, micronaut

I've successfully used the Micronaut HTTP Client with several different external services in the past.  However, I'm really struggling with one external service.  I think it might be related to the fact that the response from the external service does not contain a `Content-Type` header, but I'm not sure.

The client and response type are defined in the same groovy file.

```
package us.cloudcard.api.transact

import groovy.transform.ToString
import io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse
import io.micronaut.http.MediaType
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Body
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Post
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Produces
import io.micronaut.http.client.annotation.Client

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull

@Client('${transact.url}')
interface TransactAuthenticationClient {

    @Post
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    HttpResponse<TransactAuthenticationResponse> authenticate(@NotNull @Body String token)
}

@ToString
class TransactAuthenticationResponse {
    Boolean Expired
    String InstitutionId
    String UserName
    String customCssUrl
    String email
    String role
}
```

I'm testing it with a simple controller that just calls the client and renders the response status and body.

```
package us.cloudcard.api

import grails.compiler.GrailsCompileStatic
import grails.converters.JSON
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured
import io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import us.cloudcard.api.transact.TransactAuthenticationClient
import us.cloudcard.api.transact.TransactAuthenticationResponse

@GrailsCompileStatic
@Secured("permitAll")
class MyController {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']

    @Autowired
    TransactAuthenticationClient transactAuthenticationClient

    def show(String id) {
        String goodToken = "5753D...REDACTED...647F"
        HttpResponse response = transactAuthenticationClient.authenticate(goodToken)
        TransactAuthenticationResponse authenticationResponse = response.body()
        log.error("status: ${response.status()} body: $authenticationResponse")
        render "status: ${response.status()} body: $authenticationResponse"
    }

}
```

However, the result I get is

```
status: OK body: null
```

Making the same request in Postman results in the correct response
[image: Postman request]

When I debug, I can inspect the HttpResponse object and see all the correct headers, so I know I'm making the request successfully.  I just can't bind the response.
[image]

I tried changing the client to bind to a `String`

```
    @Post
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    HttpResponse<String> authenticate(@NotNull @Body String token)
```

and I got the following response

```
status: OK body: PooledSlicedByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 176, cap: 176/176, unwrapped: PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 484, widx: 484, cap: 513))
```

This was interesting because the `widx: 176, cap: 176/176` perfectly matched the content length of the successful response.

I am really at a loss, so I would appreciate any help you can give.

## Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR: The Micronaut HTTP Client is not designed to work for this API

The Micronaut HTTP Client cannot consume APIs that do not include a `content-type` header in the response.  I talked with Jeff Scott Brown about this, and that's just how Micronaut is designed.  If there's no `content-type` header in the response, the client won't know how to parse the response body.

#### Work-Around

```
package us.cloudcard.api.transact

import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.transform.ToString
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Component
class TransactAuthenticationClient {

    @Value('${transact.url}')
    String transactAuthenticationUrl

    TransactAuthenticationResponse workaround2(String token) {
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(transactAuthenticationUrl)
        post.addHeader("content-type", "text/plain")
        post.setEntity(new StringEntity(token))

        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()
        CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(post)

        def bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()))
        def json = bufferedReader.getText()
        println "response: \n" + json

        def resultMap = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
        return new TransactAuthenticationResponse(resultMap)
    }
}

@ToString(includeNames = true)
class TransactAuthenticationResponse {
    Boolean Expired
    String InstitutionId
    String UserName
    String customCssUrl
    String email
    String role
}
```

#### JUST FYI: Before I found the above workaround, I tried this and it also does not work.

```
    TransactAuthenticationResponse thisAlsoDoesNotWork (String token) {
        String baseUrl = "https://example.com"
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.create(baseUrl.toURL())
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.POST("/path/to/endpoint", token)
        HttpResponse<String> resp = client.toBlocking().exchange(request, String)
        String json = resp.body()
        println "json: $json"
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
        TransactAuthenticationResponse response = objectMapper.readValue(json, TransactAuthenticationResponse)
        return response
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem, this is the best solution I found so far:

```java
import io.micronaut.core.convert.ConversionService;
import io.micronaut.core.convert.TypeConverter;
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;

// (...)

ConversionService.SHARED.addConverter(ByteBuf.class, String.class, new TypeConverter<ByteBuf, String>() {
      @Override
      public Optional<String> convert(ByteBuf object, Class<String> targetType, ConversionContext context) {
          return Optional.ofNullable(object).map(bb -> bb.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
      }
});
HttpRequest<String> req = HttpRequest.POST("<url>", "<body>");
// res is instance of io.micronaut.http.client.netty.FullNettyClientHttpResponse which uses the shared conversion service as "last chance" to convert the response body
HttpResponse<String> res = httpClient.toBlocking().exchange(req);
String responseBody = res.getBody(String.class).get();
```